# funchook lib Failed to unprotect memory

Tags: c++, c, centos, arm

I wrote a mini program using Funhook(https://github.com/kubo/funchook), but it prompted an error

os: centos

arch:arm

funchook:2.0.0

```c
#include <funchook.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int  (*getpid_func)();

static int getpid_hook() {
    printf("origin getpid==%d\n",getpid_func());
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    funchook_t *funchook = funchook_create();

    getpid_func = getpid;
    funchook_prepare(funchook, (void**)&getpid_func, getpid_hook);

    if (funchook_install(funchook, 0) != FUNCHOOK_ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("%s\n", funchook_error_message(funchook));
    }

    printf("%d\n",getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
/a.out 

Failed to unprotect memory 0xfffefa947000 (size=4096, prot=read,write,exec) <- 0xfffefa9476b0 (size=8, error=Invalid argument)
3370847
```

I am running normally on x86, but this error occurred in ARM. Is it because ARM is not supported？

Comment: Either that or there is a bug somewhere. Did you check the bugtracker for the lib? Also, you could query there whether ARM is supported. It would help if you extracted a [mcve] from both the library and your code either way.